# How to debug Server-Side JavaScript Activity

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud

I have created a server-side javascript activity as follows.  I also have a automation created via automation studio which executes the server-side script.  It is succeeding each time however I don't see the update being done on the data extension.  How can I debug to see the error msg?

```
<script  runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1");

    try {

var caslDE = DataExtension.Init("6C119FFD-0EF5-476A-8127-E2E70D80ED04");

caslDE.Rows.Update({Source:"EXACT"}, ["Prospect Type"], ["A"]);

} catch (ex) {
    Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
}

</script>
```

Comment: How did you execute the server-side script from automation studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would put your code on a landing page, and test it that way.  Like so:

```
%%[ 
    VAR @Result
]%%

<script  runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core","1");

    try {

    var caslDE = DataExtension.Init("6C119FFD-0EF5-476A-8127-E2E70D80ED04");

    caslDE.Rows.Update({Source:"EXACT"}, ["Prospect Type"], ["A"]);

    } catch (ex) {
        Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
        Variable.SetValue("@Result", Stringify(ex));  //sets above ampscript variable
    }

</script>
//// some basic page html goes here/////
%%=v(@Result)=%%
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not know how to create a landing page, then I will share a complete solution of the problem.

1. Go to your sales force marketing cloud interface
2. Click on "Web Studio" -> "Cloud Pages"
3. Click on "Create Collection"
4. Click on "Create" -> "Landing Page"
5. Click on "Code View"
6. Insert your script as Timothy Said

   ```
   %%[ 
       VAR @Result
   ]%%

   <script  runat="server">

       Platform.Load("core","1");

       try {

       var caslDE = DataExtension.Init("6C119FFD-0EF5-476A-8127-E2E70D80ED04");

       caslDE.Rows.Update({Source:"EXACT"}, ["Prospect Type"], ["A"]);

       } catch (ex) {
           Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
           Variable.SetValue("@Result", Stringify(ex));  //sets above ampscript variable
       }
   ```
7. Click "save"
8. Click "schedule/publish" and wait until your preview is ready.